# Saving raster dataset using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to save filled raster object to geo database by my specified filename.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\GIS Data\Cameron_Run\Topo_NED\Projected"

# Set local variables
surfaceRaster = "raw_10m_dem"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute FlowDirection
fillRaster = Fill(surfaceRaster)
arcpy.RasterToGeodatabase_conversion(fillRaster, r"C:\GIS Data\Cameron_Run\Topo_NED
\Projected\fillRasterGDB.gdb")
```

But this code is saving raster file by its own specified name, for this case `Fill_raw_10m1` is the default name of saved raster file.

Is there any way so that I can specify the name of saved raster file?

Comment: Have you considered renaming or copy with new name raster before executing `RasterToGeodatabase` ?

Comment: `RasterToGeodatabase_conversion` doesn't provide any option to save as your specified name. You can only specify the output geo database path

Comment: Yes, thats why I proposed to RENAME raster file (i.e. with `os.rename()`) before running `RasterToGeodatabase_conversion`. You can also use [Rename](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000056000000) tool from ArcToolbox.

Comment: your paths are not in the correct format, either use raw format
r"C:\GIS Data\Cameron_Run\Topo_NED\Projected" 
or double backslashes or single foreslashes

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you've looked at ESRI's example because your comment says "Execute FlowDirection" - which is the error in ESRI's docs, but I'll pull out the important part that your code is missing - the save() method for your fill object.

Generally, the Spatial Analyst tools work a little differently in scripting than some of the other toolbox tools since they generate a return value that is an object (rather than taking input and output locations). Once you have the Fill object living in memory, you can save it using the object's save method. So, in your code above:

```
# run Fill on surfaceRaster and put output object into fillRaster
fillRaster = Fill(surfaceRaster)

# note the specification of a dataset name in the gdb below
outname = r"C:\GIS Data\Cameron_Run\Topo_NED\Projected\fillRasterGDB.gdb\fillRaster"

# save the fillRaster object to the location specified in outname
fillRaster.save(outname)
```

So, just run save, and pass in a location in order to specify where it goes. My understanding is that the RasterToGeodatabase tool doesn't accept Spatial Analyst objects as inputs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use next options:

1. If it is file-based raster then you can rename it with `os.rename()` function before using `RasterToGeodatabase_conversion` tool. But don't forget all supplementing files (i.e. tfw, ovr). I believe this is a faster method than second one.
2. You can use tool [Rename_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000056000000) from ArcToolbox in any step.

Comment: First of all, ArcGIS is saving the file by its own specified name. I'm not sure what pattern it's following to give names. If I don't know the name of file for sure, how can I rename it?

Comment: If you are talking about `Fill` then it has return value "out_surface_raster" (as stated in the help). Which I believe you can use. Have you checked example "Fill example 2 (stand-alone script)" in [Fill help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000050000000.htm) ? They are saving results there...

Comment: Oh, this is another issue. ArcGIS is not saving data in grid format, though it's saving data in `img` and `tif` format.

Comment: You can then convert it to GRID with [RasterToOtherFormat_conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000032000000) tool.